# mongoexport with sub documents and field names with spaces

Tags: mongoexport

I need to export data from a mongoDB where I have sub-documents and fields with spaces. I have tried several permutations such as:

```
mongoexport --db main --collection prices --fields _id,subdoc1.sum,subdoc1["field name 1"],subdoc1["field name 2"] --csv > out.dat
```

or

```
mongoexport --db main --collection prices --fields _id,subdoc1.sum,subdoc1."field name 1",subdoc1."field name 2" --csv > out.dat
```

There is no documentation on how to do this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can escape spaces without quotation marks on the command-line on unix-like operating systems using a backslash:

```
mongoexport --db main --collection prices --fields _id,subdoc1.sum,subdoc1.field\ name\ 1,subdoc1.field\ name\ 2 --csv >out.dat
```

And on Windows, (I think) you use the [caret](https://superuser.com/questions/279008/how-do-i-escape-spaces-in-command-line-in-windows-without-using-quotation-marks):

```
mongoexport --db main --collection prices --fields _id,subdoc1.sum,subdoc1.field^ name^ 1,subdoc1.field^ name^ 2 --csv >out.dat
```

Comment: Using backslashes does not work. Neither does using backslashes combined with my other two attempts from my initial question. Anyone with mongoexport experience have any other advice? Or is the only option to rename the fields first before export? BTW, renaming these fields is extremely time-consuming as this is a large dataset.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning what shell you're running mongoexport in. I think the space sensitivity has more to do with the shell misinterpreting your spaces than with mongoexport. The backslash technique works for me on a Mac running GNU bash 3.2.